# Combine default and named CORS policies in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web API application I'd like to enable cross-site requests to all endpoints from one origin and also cross-site requests from another origin to specific origin. (Those may also allow requests from the first origin or not - I don't care.)

So it sounds like I want a combination of a default policy and a named policy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1 talks about using each individually, but not about combining them, and I could not get this to work.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(CreateDefaultCorsPolicy);
            options.AddPolicy(OtherCorsPolicyName, CreateOtherCorsPolicy);
        });
        ...

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
         ...
         app.UseRouting();
         ...
         app.UseCors(); // Either this works...
         app.UseCors(OtherCorsPolicyName); // ... or this!
         ...
         app.UseEndpoints(SetupEndpoints);
         ...
```

Then on certain controller methods I have:

```
    [EnableCors(OtherCorsPolicyName)]
    public string SomeControllerMethod()
```

When I test it with `curl -H "Origin: TEST_ORIGIN" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" -X OPTIONS -i http://localhost:5000/...` only one of these policies works at a time. If I comment out the `app.UseCors();` then the named policy on `SomeControllerMethod` works. If I comment out `app.UseCors(OtherCorsPolicyName);` then the default policy works. Is there a way to make them work together?

I cannot even get two named policies to work together by decorating my controllers with my "default" policy - I still get no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header returned.

Comment: "Is there a way to make them work together?" Why you want to use them together? Both of them are used to set the **default** CORS policy, you should use one of the policies as the default policy, then, for another policy, you could [enable Cors with endpoint routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing) or use [`[EnableCors]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-attributes).

Comment: I tried that, but `[EnableCors(OtherCorsPolicyName)]` appeared to have no effect (I got no Access-Control headers back) unless I also had `app.UseCors(OtherCorsPolicyName)`. So maybe that's "the real problem" that I should have asked about, but I wasn't sure of it at the time.

Comment: ... of course sets `OtherCorsPolicyName` for *all* controllers, not just those - oops! Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I figured it out and posted my own answer. Thanks for pointing me onto the right track @ZhiLv!

Comment: Glad to hear you have resolved the problem, Congratulation!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using endpoint routing and, [as the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing) this does not automatically allow pre-flight requests. The fix is two-fold:

1. Call `app.UseCors()` without a policy name to add the CORS middleware to the pipeline, but without enabling CORS by default.
2. Add `[HttpOptions`] to any API methods that have `[EnableCors]` to make them support pre-flight requests.

So in Startup:

```
    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
         ...
         app.UseRouting();
         ...
         app.UseCors(); // No policy name!
         ...
         app.UseEndpoints(SetupEndpoints);
         ...
```

On controller methods:

```
    [HttpGet, HttpOptions]
    [EnableCors(OtherCorsPolicyName)]
    public string SomeControllerMethod()
```